# Validity of a proof on the differentiation of power series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

There is actually a well known theorem says :

> let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ If this series converges for $\mid x\mid<r$ Then the series $f’(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1}$ Also converges for $\mid x\mid <r.$

Here is my proof using the ratio test (it’s pretty straight forward.)

Assuming that the series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
Converges for $\mid x\mid<r$ if and only if $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\mid a_{n+1}x^{n+1}\mid}{\mid a_nx^n\mid}=\mid x\mid \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\mid a_{n+1}\mid}{\mid a_n\mid}=\mid x\mid \frac{1}{r}$$
So what we must remember here is that $\mid a_{n+1}\mid / \mid a_n\mid=1/r$

Now let’s back to our main series $f’(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1}$, and let’s use the ratio test :
$$\frac{\mid a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n\mid}{\mid a_nnx^{n-1}\mid}=\frac{\mid a_{n+1}\mid}{\mid a_n\mid}\frac{n+1}{n}\mid x\mid=L$$
Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}L= \mid x\mid \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\mid a_{n+1}\mid}{\mid a_n\mid} =\frac{|x|}{r}$$
Set this result less than $1$:
$$|x|<r$$

As desired.

Is that proof valid?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Take, for instance the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ with$$a_n=\begin{cases}2^n&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then its radius of convergence is $\frac12$. However, the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}x^{n+1}|}{|a_nx^n|}$$does not exist, for any $x\ne0$.

Comment: I didn’t know that you can make the coefficient $a_n$ like a piecewise function.

Comment: If you don't like it, you can take$$a_n=\left(\frac{3+(-1)^n}2\right)^n,$$and you will get the same $a_n$'s as before.

Comment: But where is the mistake in the proof?

Comment: The mistake lies in assuming that the limit exists.

Comment: Does this mean that the series you wrote diverges?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $\frac12$.

Comment: Well, the proof was wrong, but the theorem is right so can tell me from where should i start to prove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122370/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-yassir).